# Logging unhandled exceptions in Android Activity

Tags: java, android, exception

I have created a class `BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity` from which all my Activites in an Android App are inheriting.

In this class I intended to catch all unhandled exceptions, so I can write them to a local SQLite database for later inspection / sending to remote server.

Below I attach entire class code:

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    final Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler defaultHandler = Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();

    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        @Override
        public void uncaughtException(Thread paramThread, Throwable paramThrowable) {
            Log.e("Uncaught Exception", paramThrowable.getMessage());
            logError(paramThrowable);
            defaultHandler.uncaughtException(paramThread, paramThrowable);
        }
    });
}

private void logError(final Throwable paramThrowable){
    try {
        ApplicationError error = new ApplicationError();

        String stackTrace = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < paramThrowable.getStackTrace().length; i++) {
            stackTrace += paramThrowable.getStackTrace()[i].toString() + "\n";
        }

        Throwable tmp = paramThrowable;
        int j = 0;
        while ((tmp = tmp.getCause()) != null && j < 5) {
            j++;
            stackTrace += "Coused by:\n";
            for (int i = 0; i < tmp.getStackTrace().length; i++) {
                stackTrace += tmp.getStackTrace()[i].toString() + "\n";
            }
        }

        Log.e("Saving error...", "");

        String deviceInfo = "";
        deviceInfo += "OS version: " + System.getProperty("os.version") + "\n";
        deviceInfo += "API level: " + Build.VERSION.SDK_INT + "\n";
        deviceInfo += "Manufacturer: " + Build.MANUFACTURER + "\n";
        deviceInfo += "Device: " + Build.DEVICE + "\n";
        deviceInfo += "Model: " + Build.MODEL + "\n";
        deviceInfo += "Product: " + Build.PRODUCT + "\n";

        error.mDeviceInfo = deviceInfo;
        error.mErrorMessage = paramThrowable.getMessage();
        error.mStackTrace = stackTrace;

        error.save();

        Log.e("Saved error:", error.mErrorMessage + "\n" + error.mStackTrace);
    }catch(Exception e){

    }
}

}
```

*For clarification:* `ApplicationError` is just a model class which handles saving to the database using `DBFlow`.

**The problem**

Each time an unhandled exception occurs (doesn't matter what it is) in an activity two weird things happen:

1. The `logError()` method is called more than once, sometimes even 8-10 times. Looking at logs I can see they have almost the same timestamp.
2. A message 'XXX Application has stopped" is shown on a device screen (which is fine), but after closing it the application is hanged and I need to force-stop from application settings screen.

Can anyone help me with this? Or is there a better approach to the problem?

Comment: You know there are frameworks that will do this for you right? Crashlytics, Acra, Bugsense, etc.

Comment: Do any of these support sending the error to a custom server application during synchronization? I need to clarify that I need to store the error in a database for later sync, because it is the requirement that application logs errors for later sync even when offline.

Comment: All of them cache errors that happen offlie and send them when there's an active network connection. ACRA  (and maybe the others, I don't know) will support sending to your own custom server, I believe.

Comment: Also put `e.printStackTrace()` where you catch the Exception, then you'll see what's causing "XXX Application has stopped" in your LogCat

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to finally solve this with help of [**AAG's** answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35876515/logging-unhandled-exceptions-in-android-activity#answer-35876992).

@AAG you were right, the exception handler was being added each time an `onCreate()` method in any activity was called.

@AAG But you were wrong about not using defaultHandler. I have to use it, for Android to properly handle application crash.

Thanks for your help!

This is the fixed code:

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static Context applicationContext = null;
    public static Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler defaultHandler = null;
    public static Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler exceptionHandler = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if(defaultHandler == null){
            defaultHandler = Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();
        }

        if(applicationContext == null){
            applicationContext = getApplicationContext();
        }

        if(exceptionHandler == null){
            exceptionHandler = new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
                @Override
                public void uncaughtException(Thread paramThread, Throwable paramThrowable) {
                    Log.e("Uncaught Exception", paramThrowable.getMessage());
                    logError(paramThrowable);
                    defaultHandler.uncaughtException(paramThread, paramThrowable);

                }
            };

            Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(exceptionHandler);
        }
    }

    private static void logError(final Throwable paramThrowable){
        try {
            ApplicationError error = new ApplicationError();

            String stackTrace = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < paramThrowable.getStackTrace().length; i++) {
                stackTrace += paramThrowable.getStackTrace()[i].toString() + "\n";
            }

            Log.e("Saving error...", "");

            Throwable tmp = paramThrowable;
            int j = 0;
            while ((tmp = tmp.getCause()) != null && j < 5) {
                j++;
                stackTrace += "Coused by:\n";
                for (int i = 0; i < tmp.getStackTrace().length; i++) {
                    stackTrace += tmp.getStackTrace()[i].toString() + "\n";
                }
            }

            String deviceInfo = "";
            deviceInfo += "OS version: " + System.getProperty("os.version") + "\n";
            deviceInfo += "API level: " + Build.VERSION.SDK_INT + "\n";
            deviceInfo += "Manufacturer: " + Build.MANUFACTURER + "\n";
            deviceInfo += "Device: " + Build.DEVICE + "\n";
            deviceInfo += "Model: " + Build.MODEL + "\n";
            deviceInfo += "Product: " + Build.PRODUCT + "\n";

            error.mDeviceInfo = deviceInfo;
            error.mErrorMessage = paramThrowable.getMessage();
            error.mStackTrace = stackTrace;

            error.save();

            Log.e("Saved error:", error.mErrorMessage + "\n" + error.mStackTrace);
        }catch(Exception e){

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

in your handler, you are calling

`defaultHandler.uncaughtException(paramThread, paramThrowable);`

you should not be doing this. Everytime onCreate is called (which can be many depending on how your app is used) - you are creating a handler that calls the old handler. so the third time onCreate is call, you will call the handler that was created on the second call, and then the handler that was created on the first call.

after removing this, your onCreate method should now be:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        @Override
        public void uncaughtException(Thread paramThread, Throwable paramThrowable) {
            Log.e("Uncaught Exception", paramThrowable.getMessage());
            logError(paramThrowable);
        }
    });
```

}

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This solves the first problem partially. Without this line, the default handler is not called, so AndroidOS is not showing "Application has stopped" message and does not restart the application. In result we are in problem no 2.