# App Crashes with no Stack Trace

Tags: android, android-studio

**Preface** I've changed the title. It is hard to understand why, while debugging, sometimes uncaught exceptions print 'FATAL EXCEPTION' to the Logcat and sometimes they don't.

The simplified example below crashes when I get to the line `client1.getInputStream()`.  There is no stack trace or other indication inside of Logcat as to what went wrong.  I am running Android Studio 3.0.0beta4.

- Why is it crashing? (update - crash was due to a SecurityException)
- And why does Logcat not show a stack trace or
  other error?

**Update**
Okay, I figured out why it crashes.  I added `catch(Exception ex) {...}` and found that an exception was in fact being thrown, for I had forgotten to test for it.  Stupid error, I didn't include INTERNET permission in the manifest.

So, I would still like to know why I would get no error indication for the unhandle exception.  The app just quietly disappears.

**Edit** One commenter says

> In java, unhandled exceptions are not printed

Here is the logcat message when I force an unhandled NullPointerException

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-6729
           Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 30824
           java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.InputStream java.net.URLConnection.getInputStream()' on a null object reference
           at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.GetDataAsyncFromPlaystore(MainActivity.java:79)
           at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity$1$1.run(MainActivity.java:42)
           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

So, why not for SecurityException?

**Edit2** Just to make things more confusing, I've discovered that when I set a break point prior to the exception point, then step through the code and step over the offending line (the one causing the SecurityException), the App abruptly terminates with with no indication as to why.  If however, I hit F9 before reaching the offending line, I do, in fact, get a "FATAL EXCEPTION" message logged in Logcat.  (Therefore, I've added back the "android-studio" tag to the question.)

So, same question, slightly different wording:  Why does the exception print a 'FATAL EXCEPTION' message when debugging one way, but not the other?

**The (simplified) code**

```
public void GetDataFromWebsite()
{
    Uri queryUri = Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/search?q=Planning&c=apps");
    try {
        URL queryUrl = new URL(queryUri.toString());
        URLConnection client1 = queryUrl.openConnection();
        InputStream in = client1.getInputStream();
        Log.d("Test", "Okay");
    } catch (MalformedURLException muex) {
        Log.e("Test", "Malformed Url", muex);
    } catch (IOException ioex) {
        Log.e("Test", "IO Error", ioex);
    // } catch(Exception ex) {
    //    Log.e("Test","Other Exception", ex);
    }
}
```

**NOTE:**

Comment: of course there is no stacktrace as you are loggin exception like this: `Log.e("Test", "IO Error", ioex);`

Comment: @selvin - not a useful comment.  of course I should be testing for exceptions - I just wasn't testing for them all.  There was no log output at all.  I've since figured out the crash, but not why there was no unhandled exception printed.

Answer (score 1):

You are just catching `MalformedURLException` and `IOException`. So you won't get other exceptions.
Catch with **Exception** you will get a trace.

UnHandled exception not printed in android log cat. you can print UnHandled exception by `UncaughtExceptionHandler`. Here is a like to implement `UncaughtExceptionHandler`: [Logging unhandled exceptions in Android Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35876515/logging-unhandled-exceptions-in-android-activity)

There is no relativity between `NullpointerException` and `SecurityException`. How it will get caught by `SecurityException`.

Comment: Typically, when I am debugging an App, and it crashes - say for a NullPointerException, I see a "FATAL blah, blah, etc" message in logcat.  Why would I not see one for this unhandle exception?

Comment: In java, unhandled exceptions are not printed

Comment: Not so for NullPointerException, see updated question.  BTW, +1 for seeing the missing `catch(Exception ...` so quickly.  Thx.

Comment: No, they are related in that they both derive from RuntimeException.  However, see my updated question.  In summary, I experimented some more, and I **do** get a 'FATAL EXCEPTION' message in Logcat for both types of unhandled exceptions, but only if I use F9 to continue (if I step with a debugger, the SecurityException is not logged)